# How can I make the output file of an awk command's name unique?

Tags: awk, filenames

I'm using the command:

```
$output = shell_exec('awk -F, \'NR==FNR{seen[$0]++;next} ($1 in seen)\' uploads/a.txt uploads/b.txt > exports/output.txt');
```

How can I make the output.txt a unique name every time?

Comment: How many different filenames do you expect to generate, and what kind of filesystem(s) are they being stored on?

Comment: If you want it unique per execution, you can use `output_$$.txt`.  `$$` will get substituted by the pid of the execution.

Comment: You seem to be using php. If so use the php mechanisms, such as [tempnam](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php). (The file is only notionally *temporary*). If not then use the similar `mktemp` command.

Comment: The expected output files to be generated can be 1000's. The filename would need to be unique or randomly generated. The 'output_$$.txt' result works for me. Would there be a way of referencing the output of the execution? That way I could attach the output to a download link and always refer to the generated file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could do it from the command line:

```
awk -F, '
BEGIN {
    for (1=3; i<ARGC; i++) {
        split(ARGV[i],parts,/[_.]/)
        num = parts[2]+0
        max = (max > num ? max : num)
        ARGV[i] = ""
    }
    ARGC -= 2
    out = "exports/output_" max+1 ".txt"
    print out
}
NR==FNR { a[$0]++; next }
$1 in a { print > out }
' uploads/a.txt uploads/b.txt exports/output_*.txt
```

I'll leave it to you to add whatever you need to call it from PHP or wherever.

The above assumes that all files in your exports directory are generated by this script or otherwise follow the same `output_<number>.txt` format.

I changed your array name from `seen[]` to `a[]` because `seen[]` is idiomatically used to identify unique values in one set of input (e.g. within one file), not to test if a value appears in one file and then again in a second file as you're using it. The name `a[]` is most commonly used for that purpose.